# what is the browser interpretation of this new URL construct: /#:~:text=abcd

Tags: html, url

I'm noticing more URLs with this URL encoding,  site.com/abc/#:~:text=something
What is the browser interpretation or usage of #:~:text=
?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a Chrome-specific feature called [scroll to text fragment](https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/4733392803332096).

It is like a regular fragment identifier but allows linking to arbitrary pieces of text in a page.